# tableに行を挿入できない

Tags: javascript

javascriptの初心者です。
今headに記述したtableをプリントしたいのですが、
できなかったです。どこ間違えましたか。
教えていただけますでしょうか。
宜しくお願い致します。

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script>
    function print_table(){
        var goods = ["チェア", "デスク", "ブックスタンド"];
        var price = [4000, 12000, 800];
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            document.write("<tr>");
            document.write("<td>"+good[i]+"</td>");
            document.write("<td>"+price[i]+"円</td>");
            document.write("</tr>");
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr><th>製品名</th><th>価格</th></tr>
        <script>
            print_table();
        </script>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: 解決できました！goodじゃなく、goodsのほうが正しいです。

Comment: お疲れ様でした。スタック・オーバーフローでは自己解決した場合自己回答することができ、[また、推奨されています](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)。しばらくすると自分の回答を承認することもできますので、よろしければお願いいたします :)

Comment: タイトルには質問の内容を簡潔に書いてください。言語仕様に問題があるとも読めます。

Answer (score 4):

解決できました！goodじゃなく、goodsのほうが正しいです。